# How to increase propability of a certain number for random() in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, probability

First of all, the method I am currently using for picking up a random number within a range of 1-45 is:

```
public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
}
```

What I want to do is, suppose that there are six numbers in an array of int

```
int[] numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12];
```

and I want to increase the probability (about 20% to 30%) for picking that numbers in the array from a randomly generated number in a range of 1 ~ 45.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Which number do you mean by "that numbers"?

Comment: One way to achieve it: Separate the range into your `numbers` array and an array of the other numbers in the range. Then first do `nextDouble()` and if its `< 0.3`, you pick a random element from `numbers`. If its `> 0.7` you pick any of the other numbers. That way, the chance of getting a number from `numbers` is 30%.

Comment: @Zabuzard Your approach is good, but 0.3 is way too big.  The half dozen values don't make up 30% of the probability, even after boosting the individual p's by 30%.  The correct proportion is found by solving the relationship `6*(1.3*p) + 39*p = 1`, yielding that the subset should be chosen 1/6 of the time and the remainder 5/6 of the time.

Comment: @pjs I assumed the probability of picking one of the special numbers should be 30%. You assumed the probability should be 30% higher than any of the other ones. I'll leave it as an exercise for the readers to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java.util.Random instead of Math.random. It has nicer functions like random.nextInt().

And for the increased probability, use the approach suggested by Zabuzard's comment [How to increase propability of a certain number for random() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638802/how-to-increase-propability-of-a-certain-number-for-random-in-java/68639074#comment121304026_68638802)

```
static final int[] numbers = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12};

static final Random random = new Random();

public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    int p = random.nextInt(10);
    if (p < 3) {
        return numbers[random.nextInt(numbers.length)];
    } else {
        return min + random.nextInt(max - min);
    }
}
```

Here, 30% of the time, we pick one of the 6 'special' numbers, and 70% of the time, we pick one of the numbers in the min-max range.

I'm not sure if that is exactly what you want, but you can tweak the ratio until you find something that matches your needs.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to extend the range of the random selected, 1-45 in your case, to include `(factor-1)*numbers.length` additional values, where you want numbers in the array to be `factor` times more likely. You then select random numbers from this extended range. If the value is less than 45 you use it directly, if it's above you calculate the corresponding position in the array of numbers.

This approach can be made to work with fractional values of `factor`, but at the cost of increased code complexity. Let me know in the comments if this is an issue and I'll provide an edit.

Here's some code to illustrate:

```
int min = 1;
int max = 45;

int range = 1 + max - min;

int factor = 3;
int[] numbers = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12};

int randomRange = range + (factor-1)*numbers.length;

Random rand = new Random();

int[] h = new int[max];

for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
    int p = rand.nextInt(randomRange);
    
    if(p < range)
        p  += min;
    else
        p = numbers[(p-range)/(factor-1)];
                
    h[p-min]++;
}
```

And the corresponding graph of `h`:

[image]

Comment: I think you need some cleanup for when `factor` is non-integer.  The question proposed a factor of 1.2 to 1.3.